# is padding ViewPager in order to view multiple pages bad practice?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, multiple-columns, padding

Basically, I'm trying to create a **3 day calendar view**. My example is working so far as shown in the screenshot. The **pages 'snap'** as well.
[screenshot on ViewPager with multiple views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yknNT.png)

In order to achieve **multiple pages visible at the same time** I used the following:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        **android:paddingRight="200dp"**
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

The padding is set to 200dp. **Is this a very hacky method?** It also leaves 200dp empty space on the far right at the end of the list. (Obviously I would handle the padding in java code to make calculations such as a third of the screen)

Also am I implementing my calendar the right way?

Comment: [CommonsBlog - Multiple-View ViewPager Options](https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html)   (a lil dated, but still great reading)

Answer (score 0):

@petey recommended from a great source:

> The key, of course, is to override getPageWidth() in your PagerAdapter:
>
> @Override public float getPageWidth(int position) { return(0.5f); }